# What to define so website looks the same on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to create a website that looks the same on every browser.
I use a font of 13px, and every margin and padding is defined as pixels.
Here I created 3 div's so that the leftpart, the middlepart and the rightpart all align vertically. These 3 divs ar wrapped in the "upper"-div.
On my desktop (IE and Chrome) it looks good, and aligned.
But when I want to view my site on my mobile, the middle and right part are higher then the left.
Is there a property I am forgetting to define which has a different default setting in each type of browser?

Thank you so much.
Here is the code i'm using:

```
<div class="left">

<form method="post" action="small.php">
<input type="hidden" name='form' value='wasSubmited' />
<input type="submit" name="1" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:33px">
<input type="submit" name="2" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:33px">
<input type="submit" name="3" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:20px">
<input type="submit" name="4" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:20px"> 
</form>
</div>

<div class="middle">
<p style="margin-top:25px">Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla</p>
<p style="margin-top:24px">Bla bla bla</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px">Bla bla bla</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px">Bla bla bla</p>
</div>

<div class="right">
<p style="margin-top:46px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance1)); ?>%</p>
<p style="margin-top:24px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance2)); ?>%</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance3)); ?>%</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance4)); ?>%</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.upper {
width:850px;
position:absolute;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:#e7eef9;
left:75px;
top:50px;
border:1px solid;
height:477px;
overflow:hidden;
}

div.left {
width:70px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
padding:0px 20px 0px 40px;
text-align:left;
height:320px;
padding-top:50px;
}

div.middle {
width:300px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
height:320px;
padding-top:50px;
}

div.right {
width:100px;
margin:0px;
float:right;
background-color:#d7e3f5;
height:320px;
padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the CSS to be able to answer.

Comment: Added. thank you for looking into my question ;)

Comment: a css reset might help ensure that you're site looks the same cross browser. It resets the default values for tags then you build from the ground up, look up eric meyers reset then remove the tags you don't want to reset.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the source of your problem is related to this line in your css:

```
padding:0px 20px 0px 40px;
```

under the `div.left {` selector.

The middle and right divs only have top padding, which explains why they are being displayed differently.

Comment: you are probably right. At this moment I re-did the page, putting everything in containers seperatly (so every line is in a DIV).
The problem is partially over now. I now noticed that the PX size of the fonts are differently displayed. Have you got an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing the entire page and the browsers you're using but some possible reasons are: 1. You might have not defined a font-family, so some browsers might be using different default fonts. Try explicitly defining a **web safe** font-family for the entire document. 2: It doesn't look like you have explicitly defined a font-size either. You should do this. 3: Remember that submit buttons are always very particular in terms of styling across browsers, so if you want a consistent style on these, you should create your own custom button using <a> tags and then use JS to submit

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as your accepted answer, as this helps me build my reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

The middle and right part become higher than the left because when the screen is smaller, the `div` gets pushed down as there isn't enough room. You can fix this by placing everything in a container. Like so:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- use a container -->
<div class="left">

<form method="post" action="small.php">
<input type="hidden" name='form' value='wasSubmited' />
<input type="submit" name="1" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:33px">
<input type="submit" name="2" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:33px">
<input type="submit" name="3" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:20px">
<input type="submit" name="4" value="Attempt" style="margin-top:20px"> 
</form>
</div>

<div class="middle">
<p style="margin-top:25px">Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla</p>
<p style="margin-top:24px">Bla bla bla</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px">Bla bla bla</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px">Bla bla bla</p>
</div>

<div class="right">
<p style="margin-top:46px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance1)); ?>%</p>
<p style="margin-top:24px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance2)); ?>%</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance3)); ?>%</p>
<p style="margin-top:22px"><?php echo max(0,round($chance4)); ?>%</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.upper {
width:850px;
position:absolute;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:#e7eef9;
left:75px;
top:50px;
border:1px solid;
height:477px;
overflow:hidden;
}

div.left {
width:70px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
padding:0px 20px 0px 40px;
text-align:left;
height:320px;
padding-top:50px;
}

div.middle {
width:300px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
height:320px;
padding-top:50px;
}

div.right {
width:100px;
margin:0px;
float:right;
background-color:#d7e3f5;
height:320px;
padding-top:50px;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px; /*or whatever width you want, but the container has to be at least as big as the total width of everything inside*/
}
```

Comment: I have everything in a container already!  It is called "upper" in my CSS. I just was missing the line in this post because there was a lot of code in between, sorry